# How to print a text from inside a command without affecting its width?

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I am trying to print within a command, but after printing I see the text (command's argument) to be printed with changed length...

I wonder if there is a reason of that and how can I avoid it.

I will try to answer my question... but probably I will not give the best answer... So, If you want, you can try to answer...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength\parskip{10pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{
#1
}


\begin{document}



\section{In a section}

This is a text that will occupy  one full line and some more, I hope I can show it



\myprint{This is a text that will occupy  one full line and some more, I hope I can show it}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There are two space tokens in your `\myprint` macro. Put % at the end of the two lines.

Comment: I don't want to change the first line... I just want to have the same output from my command and from the actual text in the body... I did not understood about the 'space tokens'... I will google it...

Comment: There's a space after the `{` and one after the `#1` from the new lines. You need to add a comment character after both to prevent that.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7459/647 for how that works.

Comment: … or write the definition `\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{#1}` all on the same line.  Incidentally, *in your example* the first space actually has no effect because occurs in vertical mode; it will not be so in general.

Comment: In other words: change your command to `\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{#1}` or something equivalent. What you have now is equivalent to `\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{ #1 }` which has more spaces.

Comment: I just tested \newcommand{\myprint}[1]{
%#1%} and it works fine... Thank you both... It is not exactly a dupplicate.. but can consider to be... If someone of you want to write in an answer what have already said I will accept it as answer (It was in more lines... can not show it here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spurious spaces (marked with `<--`).  I also removed your bogus parameters for `\parskip` and `\parindent`.  If you don't want to indent a single paragraph, use `\noindent`.  If you do not want to indent *every* paragraph, use the `parskip` package but this will make typographers' eyes bleed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{% <--
#1% <--
}

\begin{document}

\noindent This is a text that will occupy  one full line and some more, I hope I can show it

\noindent\myprint{This is a text that will occupy  one full line and some more, I hope I can show it}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Henri Menke... I forgot the parskip and parident commands there.. I use parskip package and just removed it for the MWE... this is thwe answer of TH above... I already show it works fine... for cases that we don't use a paragraph as our variable this way is better than my minipage because can be used inline too

Comment: @koleygr, I think you should ask about whatever your real question is. There's nothing here that would work differently with a paragraph.

Comment: @TH. if i use mh print command inline line text\myprint{2ndtext} the way of the minipage is different from yours... This is what I mentioned above... It is not only for me the question... May be other people find some thinks they need to know and this is why I made this general question and keeping it general... Thanks

Comment: @koleygr, Perhaps I misunderstood. I simply meant that `\myprint` defined with `\newcommand\myprint[1]{#1}` doesn't have different behavior when its argument has a paragraph or not. It sounds like you want your `\myprint` macro to start a new paragraph. If that's the case, then you want `\newcommand\myprint{\par#1}`. But since you haven't said what _you're_ trying to do, we can really only guess.

Comment: @TH. I have solved my problem .. but I will edit my ansewer to make it usefull for others... What we discussed in the comments is enough but I think it would be better  to be available as a accepted answer to others... thanks... I will edit my answer and make it good including what you said

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Long answer to understand what happens**

(For shorter answer look at @Henri Menke's answer)

Many LaTeX users are also programmers, and being a LaTeX user you become somehow a kind of programmer. Coding has some rules on styling our structure and so writing a C program we may choose between the following styles:

1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
     printf("Loop Count i=%d",i);
  }
     return 0;
}
```

2.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   int i=0;
   for (i=0;i<10;i++){
      printf("Loop Count i=%d",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

or 3.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   int i=0;
   for (i=0;i<10;i++){printf("Loop Count i=%d",i);}
   return 0;
}
```

In C programming the result is exactly the same but something similar in LaTeX coding will not have the same results.

#### Empty lines

One reason is that in LaTeX coding, an empty line is equivalent to a \par command and inserts a paragraph. So the next example will generate the following output:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{8pt}

\setlength{\parskip}{15pt}
\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{

#1

}


\begin{document}



\section{In a section}

First line in first section

\def\mymaintext{This is my  text that will occupy a big part of remaining line.}

Test before.\mymaintext
Test line after.

Test before.\myprint{\mymaintext}
Test line after.
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Spaces

By removing the empty lines we remove the \par commands from our print command but we don't remove the spaces:

```
\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{
#1
}
```

The above command will generate an extra space before our argument (we will have one space there) and an extra space after (two spaces after).

The following changes are equivalent:

```
\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{#1}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{%
#1%
}
```

and we have removed the extra empty spaces.

For more look at the topic [of space tokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7459/647) that @TH. gave me in the comments of the question.

---

**The following answer was my first answer before understanding exactly what happens and I'm leaving it here for someone who will read the comments**

I don't really know why it happens, but I found that a solution is to print in a minipage of width=\linewidth.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength\parskip{10pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\myprint}[1]{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
#1
\end{minipage}
}


\begin{document}



\section{In a section}

This is a text that will occupy  one full line and some more, I hope I can show it



\myprint{This is a text that will occupy  one full line and some more, I hope I can show it}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Almost every time someone suggests using a minipage, it is unnecessary. This is no exception.

Comment: lol... minipages have saved me from many problems... And many noobs too :P
@TH does minipage affects the rest of my text.. like space between paragraphs etc?

Comment: No. It's just rarely the right solution. Sometimes it is, but less often than I see it used.

Comment: Thanks @TH I am going to use it with paragraphs as arguments.. So I think for my use it is a solution... thanks again!

Comment: You should most definitely change `\end{minipage}` to `\end{minipage}%` -- unless you really want to generate a (in my view entirely spurious) additional `\parskip` at the end of the `myprint` environment...

Comment: Your code is wrong. Add some text *after* the \myprint line to see the problems. Or remove the `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`. And check the log-file: you get underfull warnings there.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect, sorry. The error in the question is two spurious space tokens and the revised code here has four spurious space tokens and introduces an unnecessary box which will prevent page breaking and would produce unwanted indention if parskip wans't zero.

Comment: Good job trying to understand what happens! I think the part about blank lines (and `\par`) is less relevant, and this (revised) answer would be better if you put the main part first (about your original code in the question, which only introduces spaces), and only later (if you want) the part with a blank line (which introduces a `\par`). Cheers,

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I just tried to do the changes you said... but I am losing the point of all the answer... Empty lines have more obvious results than the spaces and helps to get to the point of the space tokens. So, thanks for the advice but I think it is more useful like this. (At least for them who knows as little as I did.)

Comment: @koleygr Sure, you are the best judge on what is more informative to you. I made some formatting changes to your answer, feel free to revert if you think they don't help. By the way the answer is still wrong, because you say *“The space in the end of our command is created by the closing bracket '}' that always leave a space to separate the enclosed variable (or text) from the following text”* and this is not true at all. (In the place you use the macro, you have a line break between `\myprint{\mymaintext}` and `Test line after` and that's a space; the closing `}` never introduces a space.)

Comment: Thank you very much @ShreevatsaR ... You are right that I had made a mistake there... I fixed that. Thanks...

Comment: Looks correct now, upvoted :-) I appreciate you trying to understand, and trying to make it informative for others.